# Не работает аутентификация в firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Я новичок в JS и Firebase, так что сильно не пинайте
Следующий код должен должен захватить имя пользователя и пароль и передать его в firebase, но выдает такую ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at auth.js:24
Что же не так?

Код на HTML

```
<card class="auth">
    <h1 class="auth-title">Auth</h1>
    <h2 class="auth-text">Enter an email and password below to sign up or log in</h2>
        <input id="txtEmail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required class="input-field">

        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="input-field">

        <button class="medium-button auth-title" id="btnLogin" type="submit" autofocus>Log In</button>

        <button class="medium-button auth-title" id="btnSignUp" type="submit" autofocus>Sign Up</button>
</card>
```

Код на JS

```
const txtEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail");
const txtPassword = document.getElementById("txtPassword");
const btnSignUp = document.getElementById("btnSignUp");
const btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");

btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

});

btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
    if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log(firebaseUser)
    } else {
        console.log("not logged in");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На лицо, что выполняется код до загрузки страницы. Попробуйте или проверку до события или онлоад на загрузку страницы.

```
const btnLogin = document.getElementById("btnLogin");
if(btnLogin ){
  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));

});
```

}

```
window.onload=function(){
  и ваш код..
}
```

Comment: Оказалось, что достаточно перенести <script src="script/auth.js"></script> в конец файла)) Спасибо